# No bean named 'mongoTemplate' available. Spring Boot + MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm building a backend using Spring Boot and MongoDB, first I'm making the user repository, service, and controller, and getting this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.package.package.controller.UserController required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Here's the code:

UserController:

```
package com.package.package.controller;

import com.package.package.entities.User;
import com.package.package.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id) {
        return userRepository.findBy_id(id);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public void modifyUserById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id, @Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        user.set_id(id);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        user.set_id(ObjectId.get());
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable ObjectId id) {
        userRepository.delete(userRepository.findBy_id(id));
    }
}
```

UserRepository:

```
package com.package.package.repositories;

import com.package.package.entities.User;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    User findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
}
```

UserService:

```
package com.package.package.service;

import com.package.package.entities.User;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {
    User save(User user);
    User findbyid(ObjectId _id);
    List<User> getAll();
    void delete(User user);
}
```

MainApplication:

```
package com.package.package;

import com.package.package.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am using as a reference a past project that I made (the difference is that this was done with postgres).
Any other information you want, just tell me.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Here's the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.wazzka</groupId>
    <artifactId>wazzka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wazzka</name>
    <description>WazzkaProject</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <spring.framework.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Lovelace-SR9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you include `spring-boot-starter-mongodb`? I recommend using past projects for _reference_ but generating new ones with https://start.spring.io.

Comment: That solved the issue, but now I'm getting this problem: https://justpaste.it/8ermn. Now the post has the pom.xml, just in case.

Comment: Do not specify versions when using Boot unless absolutely required. You're _explicitly_ (1) importing the Spring Data Lovelace train (this is fine), (2) specifying 2.2.3 for Commons and JPA, and (3) specifying 3.0.3 for MongoDB. Little surprise if you're getting incompatibilities.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: even adding with this lines I m getting the error, any other solutions?

Comment: After adding this, I just had to make sure that my mongo service was running:  for OSX `brew services start mongodb-community`

Answer (score 5):

While this is certainly ***not the reason for the error in most cases***, the fact that it happened to me and I spent a fair amount of time looking for the reason made me want to post "the solution" here.

In my case I forgot to remove these lines again after disabling autoconfiguration initially (application.yml):

```yaml
spring.autoconfigure.exclude:
  - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
  - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully, this answer too can help someone.

If you have following annotation with the parameter somewhere in your code block remove it.

```
exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class}
```

Ex: Before

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

After

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

Answer (score 2):

I Had

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Just removed the version tag and its worked